# Microsoft Teams App Studio - can't open Manifest editor and Card editor

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-appstudio

After installing App Studio, both `Manifest editor` and `Card editor` tabs are blank. `Control Library` shows correctly. Any way to troubleshoot what is causing this? Perhaps some permission issues?

EDIT: pic [details about the error when in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVW3t.png)

Comment: Can you tell us more about what  tools are you using for this? What OS are you on? Isn't there any log visible? That would be a good start to troubleshoot.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i should've formed my question better. I'm using  Microsoft Teams Version 1.2.00.24753 (64-bit), AppStudio 1.3.0 on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017. I can't see anything relevant captured in the log file frim ..AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\logs.txt

Comment: further to this, if I try to navigate to https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/manifesteditor3.html?theme=default#/ I get the response: This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.

Comment: could this be a certificate or proxy issues? pinging dev.teams.microsoft.com returns 192.229.210.194 and navigating in my browser to that IP shows an invalid cert issued to *.vo.msecnd.net which is Windows Azure CDN.

Answer (score 0):

If Developer Prewiew has been enabled([how to enable developer preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-intro#on-a-desktop-or-web-client)), You can use "Get logs" menu from right-click Microsoft Teams icon at right bottom corner of your taskbar, this is used for throubleshooting.

If you just want to edit menifest, you can do the same thing on https://teams.microsoft.com. BTW, it can be used for troubleshooting as F12 developer tool over there.

I am using the same version of Microsoft Teams and App Studio on Windows 10, Everything is ok, like below:
[image: Version of Teams and App Studio]
[image: Menifest editor available]

**wish you post further information, it will help to resolve your issue.**

Comment: thanks for your comments, I added a screenshot with the errors when trying to access in browser. That is what I looked at that ultimately made me think it's a certificate or proxy issue.